# C++ CMake-based project : How to batch build all configurations and types at once?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cross-compiling

### **C++ CMake-based project** : How to batch build all configurations and types at once ?

When working on a cross-plateform, cross-compilers CMake-based project,
which efficient way should I choose to test my changes against all build-configuration and build-type at once ?
The goal here is to avoid manual switching between all configurations, which is time-consuming.

#### Context

Using Ms Visual Studio, I have a large codebase that target many compilers and plateforms.
Non-Windows configurations use `MsVs` cross-plateform system, to `WSL` and `Dockers` containers.

> For instance, here are few - *main* - configurations, *others use specific custom compilation options*.
>
> - Windows-x64-Debug
> - Windows-x64-Release
> - Winndows-x64-ClangCL-Debug
> - Winndows-x64-ClangCL-Release
> - Linux-Clang-libc++-Debug
> - Linux-Clang-libc++-Release
> - Linux-Clang-libstdc++-Debug
> - Linux-Clang-libstdc++-Release
> - Linux-GCC-Debug
> - Linux-GCC-Release

FYI, the team working on this project start creating various CI check to avoid any non-compiling code on pull-requests.
However, the idea here is to find a way to bulk test compilation all at once, before the developer commit it.

Note that [MsVs Batch build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-build-multiple-configurations-simultaneously?view=vs-2019) do not work with CMake-based projects.

Comment: If you have docker images for each config, you can simply run all of them at once. It makes sense if you have strong machine with multiple CPUs and enough RAM. CMake itself doesn't have any build in feature like "build everything in every config".

Comment: When you write your CI get it to run a batch/bash/powershell/python script then you can just run the same script locally yourself

Comment: @pptaszni Not exactly for each configurations. Some works for multiples configuration (for instance, I have a Fedora with Clang and GCC, and Ubuntu-s from 14.04 to 20.04 as well), others works with some specific, non-trivial OS and/or toolchains.
Also some build containers are shared with other users, with large quotas, some can be run locally.

The ideal solution here is to find, or create, a convenient way to batch build most, if not all, configurations at once.